# Endpoint with multipart: Quart-Schema only shows 'application/x-www-urlencoded' in Swagger

Tags: python, swagger, multipartform-data, quart

I'm using Quart-Schema and have defined an endpoint for a multipart call with the help of https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart-schema/how_to_guides/request_validation.html.

Looks like this:

```
@dataclass
class File:
    file: Optional[UploadFile] = None
    title: Optional[str] = None
    description: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None


@bp.post('/<int:entity_id>/files')
@validate_request(File, source=DataSource.FORM)
async def post_file(data: File, entity_id):
    """Add file for entity to database"""
```

The important bit is `source=DataSource.FORM` so it will pick up the form data instead of expecting JSON.

Works great!
And this is how it looks in Swagger (auto-generated docs):

[image: Swagger multipart call]

It correctly shows all the fields and types and even includes an upload button. The only issue is, the request body type in Swagger is defined as `application/x-www-urlencoded` (only option in the drop-down). When I try out this request, it works when only sending plain field data, but when I add a file, it fails.

I can see no way to change this to `multipart/form-data` although I've seen Swagger examples showing this (though these examples don't use Quart-Schema, unfortunately).

It seems `source=DataSource.FORM` determines the request body type. Since there are only two options for `source` (the other one being `DataSource.JSON`) I see no way of getting Swagger to show/send `multipart/form-data`.

Is this a limitation of Quart-Schema, and if so: is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the quart-schema==0.17.0

Here's link to the fixed [github-issue](https://github.com/pgjones/quart-schema/commit/766666d04a112e076a3b2945834e7f461d197a04)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I can see they indeed now added a multipart/form type. I just tried to update my server, but ran into all sorts of incompatible versions issues (pip). Once resolved, no more errors on the server, but now the front-end is returning CORS errors... So apparently upgrading is not working. I'll have to completely reinstall the server to see if it now works/is resolved.